# Imposing sortal restrictions on functions in the untyped lambda calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus

In the simply typed lambda calculus if we have an addition operator, $+ : n \to n \to n$, its typing imposes that we can only combine it with something of a given type. So if $n$ is the type of natural numbers, we can only combine $+$ with things of type $n$.

In the untyped lambda calculus can we invent a function which only allows us to combine two numbers together, computing their sum?

I thought that in the untyped lambda calculus if we have a function $\lambda x,y. add \, y \, x$ then $x$ and $y$ could be substituted for by anything. For example, if we had a constant $John$ which denotes a human being named `John', then we could derive:

$$\lambda y. add \, y \, john$$

If we want $add$ to be a function on numbers and not humans, how is this ruled out in the untyped lambda calculus?

Comment: I do not understand the question. Can you please provide an example of what you would like to get?

Comment: @Andrej Bauer: I'll add more explanation.